# How do I get LogStreamId in snap_start AWS lambda functions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I used to save my LogStreamId of lambda in database for co-relation of logStreamId with a business event.
When I started using AWS Snap_Start feature of AWS lambda logStreamId is set to null and I guess reason is following -

> AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME, AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME – The name of
> the Amazon CloudWatch Logs group and stream for the function. The
> AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME and AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME environment
> variables are not available in Lambda SnapStart functions.

So my question is how do I get cloudwatch logStreamId in SnapStart lambda functions